# Fill an ASP.NET Form from a Word Document

Tags: .net, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-word

It's possible to fill an ASP.NET Form (MVC 4) reading (or importing) a Word Document?

**Update**

We have an standard document for our pricing agreements and quotations, and what I would like  implement is read that document (maybe later they want to upload the document to a dropbox account or similar service) and fill the form to create a new project in the application. The document contains the same titles only change the items, prices, etc.

Thanks for your time

Regards

Comment: I think you're going to have to give a little more detail here. Are people using a Word document you provided them with and just filling in some fields? Are they uploading the file to your server?

Comment: Well We have a standard document of our pricing agreements and quotations and what I would like to do is read that file and fill the form fields, for example Date, ID of quotations, total price, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Client side

   - a) Using a converter (An executable)
   - b) Using component (i.g. ActiveX...)
2. Server side

Server side processing of MS Word document is much easier to handle for both client and you. After document was uploaded to a temporary folder on your server you can easily get access to it and since the format is unique and known to you, data could be extracted easily. You can then store it to database or show it on a filled form to user while any missing data could added by client in that form.

There are many code samples available for reading MS Word documents on the [web](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=reading+ms+word+using+c#&oq=c#+reading+ms+word&gs_l=hp.1.1.0i30j0i8i30l2.2061.6177.0.9455.18.16.0.2.2.1.501.7114.4-15j1.16.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.rtLP1azrDw8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.bGE&fp=c20a49455b2cdf23&biw=1200&bih=644).